# Python treats the rest of the word as if it were speech marks

Tags: python, encryption

I'm new to python and I made a program that encrypts text. The only problem are the speech marks and apostrophes.At first it didn't seem a problem, I made an if statement that would add a "`" if there was an apostrophe or speech mark, my decryption program could then convert it back.

```
elif word[lettercount] == "'" or word[lettercount] == '"':
      Newletter = ("`")
```

However, say the word I wanted encrypted was "You're" it would come out a bit like this:`

````
<JT```
````

As you can see the last three letters have been treated as though they were apostrophes as well. If I typed "You're amazing!" it would come out as:

````
<]p``` -2-*.!?
````

so ye... it only turns the rest of the word it's in and then goes back to normal.

I tried:

```
Plaintext = Input.replace("'", "`")
```

and

```
Plaintext = Input.replace('"', "`")
```

but the same thing happens. Thx in advance and sorry if I'm incredibly noobie.

This is the part that converts each letter in a word:

```
        for f in range(wlen):
        torf = True
        while torf == True:
            if word[lettercount] == "'" or word[lettercount] =='"':
                Nlett = "`"
                torf = False
            elif word[lettercount] == CS[ccount]:
                if (ccount + key) >= CSlen:
                    Nlett = (CS[(key-(CSlen-ccount))])
                else:
                    Nlett = CS[(ccount + key)]
                torf = False
                lettercount = lettercount + 1
                ccount = 0
            else:
                ccount = ccount + 1
        eword = eword + Nlett
    etran = (etran + eword + "~")
print(etran)
```

sorry  if this is incredibly dumb and obvious :(

Comment: I think you better provide the *full* encryption algorithm since now it is hard to guess. Perhaps `lettercount` is not updated properly or `word is modified...

Comment: Why does an encryption program care what the characters are? Why do quotes cause problems?

Comment: Fix the indentation of the `for` loop. Why doesn't it ever use the variable `f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's still some code missing before we can see exactly what you're doing, but it appears that `wlen` is the length of the current word, and if that's the case, I think the issue is that you're not incrementing `lettercount` when you see a `'` or `"`. As a result, the first block of your `if` statement will continue testing `True` for the remainder of the word. Looks like you want:

```
if word[lettercount] == "'" or word[lettercount] =='"':
    Nlett = "`"
    torf = False
    lettercount += 1
```

Comment: Thx! it worked.(I'm so dumb I spent ages staring at my computer screen)